# how to type function within object inline?

Tags: typescript

given a type like:

```
type SomeFunctionType = (arg: string) => string
```

it it possible to apply this type to a function within an object inline? Basically apply the type `SomeFunction` to `someFunction` below.

```
const someObject = {
  someFunction: (arg) => arg
}
```

The only ways I've found is either to have the function outside the object:

```
const someFunction: SomeFunctionType = (arg) => arg

const someObject = {
  someFunction
}
```

or to type the object:

```
const someObject: { someFunction: SomeFunctionType } = {
  someFunction: (arg) => arg
}
```

but it feels like there should be a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type casting any individual value is done with `as`.

```
const someObject = {
  someFunction: ((arg => arg) as SomeFunctionType)
}
```

Or fully type the function so it matches your intended type:

```
const someObject = {
  someFunction: (arg: string): string => arg
}
```

But most of the time you probably do want provide an interface at the object level. But it's hard to advise on that with only a contrived example.